# Why are my pkgconfig "--param" compile options getting removed by CMake? How can I preserve the pkgconfig information?

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++, clang, pkg-config

A project I'm currently working on requires a dependency that has pkg-config support. CMake currently does everything right with one exception, several of the cxx-flags have a `--param` prefix to indicate specific constraints to the optimizer.

CMake takes the following from the pkg-config *.pc file in a dependency `--param optimizer_a=10000 --param optimizer_b=10000` and converts it into `--param;optimizer_a=10000;--param;optimizer_b=10000` in the CMakeCache.txt.

When `make` is executed with `VERBOSE=1`, the following output appears: `--param optimizer_a=10000 optimizer_b=10000`. A compilation error is thrown and the build terminates. CMake is supposed to prefix 'optimizer_b' with a '--param'.

CMake documentation gives the impression it handles this compiler flag correctly and it has documented support for space delimited compiler flags; it looks like CMake is correctly handling the first use of `--param` and is "skipping over" the subsequent uses of `--param`.

Why does this happen?

Is there a preferred method for handling this situation?

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your `CMakeLists.txt `w/ package find and your target parts

Comment: @zaufi - will post couple samples today

Comment: @zaufi the bottom line is a renamed version of the variable in the pkg-config file. 

"DEPENDENCYNAME_LDFLAGS=-O3 --param max-inline-insns-single=35000 --param inline-unit-growth=10000 --param large-function-growth=200000 -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-unused -Wunused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-address"

Comment: oh ok. when I wrote my answer, I wasn't aware that these weren't compile options that you were writing yourself. could you please provide a [mre] to help me set up the problem on my end to play around with it?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [CMake's compile option deduplication feature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#option-de-duplication). The explanation of and solution to this problem is stated in the docs:

> The final set of options used for a target is constructed by accumulating options from the current target and the usage requirements of its dependencies. The set of options is de-duplicated to avoid repetition.
>
> *New in version 3.12*: While beneficial for individual options, the de-duplication step can break up option groups. For example, `-option A -option B` becomes `-option A B`. One may specify a group of options using shell-like quoting along with a `SHELL:` prefix. The `SHELL:` prefix is dropped, and the rest of the option string is parsed using the [`separate_arguments()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/separate_arguments.html#command:separate_arguments) `UNIX_COMMAND` mode. For example, `"SHELL:-option A" "SHELL:-option B"` becomes `-option A -option B`.

---

Bonus (useless) info: Depending on how the tool that reads the compile options does its parsing, you may also be able to solve the problem by wrapping the prefix and what it prefixes together as one string, like `target_compile_options(my_target "--param optimizer_a=10000" "--param optimizer_b=10000")` (it depends on whether the tool implements parsing arguments passed in that form). This info is technically useless because there's the proper solution stated above, but I thought I might as well mention this.

Comment: Thank you. This is good background information that diagnosis the underlying problem. So you suggest that I need to manually loop over list of values cmake loaded from the pkgconfig file and make a new list where the --params are prefixed with the string "SHELL:"?

Comment: *the list of values

Comment: @clmsn workarounds like you suggested are possible, but I'm curious to understand the problem better / deeper first. I just commented on your question post. Please see that.

Comment: I'll throw together a base case and post something soon.

Comment: I'd suggest taking an existing pkgconfig file `$INSTALL_DIR/lib/pkgconfig` and adding something like this to the `LD_FLAGS` variable for the package. In this example case, the library is called `DEPENDENCY` :: `DEPENDENCY_LDFLAGS=-O3 --param max-inline-insns-single=35000 --param inline-unit-growth=10000 --param large-function-growth=200000 -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-unused -Wunused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-address`

Comment: cmake's deduplication logic loads DEPENDENCY_LDFLAGS and collapses the `--param` variables into a single `--param`. so when the linker engages, it breaks b/c cmake feeds it `--param max-inline-insns-single=35000 inline-unit-growth=10000 large-function-growth=200000 -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-unused -Wunused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-address` the linker can't make sense of the `--param` applied in 1 place, the arguments `inline-unit-growth=10000 large-function-growth=200000 -Wno-array-bounds` are breaking things; the linker requires `--param` in front of them